# How to verify a CNN encoder works as expected?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, pytorch, autoencoder

I am using CNN as a part of kernel warping. The purpose here is to reduce input dimension (from N*M to K *1). The input data is not image data. I suspected that the CNN network might not work as I expected. How can I verify my assumption? I am using pytorch, by the way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify the encoder efficiency than it is better to design some down stream task like classification, similarity , etc. Based on that u can validate your encoder. U may refer this link [for downstream Task](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).